# Get the last N rows in the database in order?

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have the following database table:

```
 record_id | record_date | record_value
-----------+-------------+--------------
         1 | 2010-05-01  |       195.00
         2 | 2010-07-01  |       185.00
         3 | 2010-09-01  |       175.00
         4 | 2010-05-01  |       189.00
         5 | 2010-06-01  |       185.00
         6 | 2010-07-01  |       180.00
         7 | 2010-08-01  |       175.00
         8 | 2010-09-01  |       170.00
         9 | 2010-10-01  |       165.00
```

I want to grab the last 5 rows with the data ordered by record_date ASC. This is easy to do with:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY record_date ASC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 4
```

Which would give me:

```
 record_id | record_date | record_value
-----------+-------------+--------------
         6 | 2010-07-01  |       180.00
         7 | 2010-08-01  |       175.00
         3 | 2010-09-01  |       175.00
         8 | 2010-09-01  |       170.00
         9 | 2010-10-01  |       165.00
```

But how do I do this when I don't know how many records there are and can't compute the magic number of 4?

I've tried this query, but if there are less than 5 records, it results in a negative OFFSET, which is invalid:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY record_date ASC LIMIT 5 
    OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable) - 5;
```

So how do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Why don't you just order the opposite way?

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY record_date DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

If you don't want to flip back correctly in the application, you can nest a query and flip them twice:

```sql
SELECT sub.*
    FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM mytable 
          ORDER BY record_date DESC
          LIMIT 5
         ) sub
    ORDER BY record_date ASC;
```

... which turns out to be a pretty cheap operation.

Comment: For the first query: because I don't want to have to sort it in the application. For the second query: worked perfectly, but doesn't fit nicely into my DAL. Oh well. Thanks!

Comment: @Travis Second query gives an error. Nested query must be followed by an AS [query_name] statement before ORDER BY

Comment: @AndyStowAway: That might be a limitation of your implementation. I'm fairly sure that anonymous subqueries are okay (I know they work in Postres and MySQL).

Comment: How could I implement this with predefined columns?

Comment: Replace the `*` in either of the queries with the columns you want. It doesn't matter which one you pick -- the query planner will end up doing the same thing.

Comment: ORDER BY record_date ASC is redundant. By default the ORDER BY is always ASC. So it should be ORDER BY record_date. And in your inner query you need an alias. Each derived table should have alias. Otherwise it will trigger an error: [42601] ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias.

Comment: @ReinierGarcia: use of `ASC` is to be explicit for the purposes of demonstration.

Answer (score 18):

This should work:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY record_date DESC LIMIT 5
)
SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY record_date ASC;
```

Comment: yes, this is a great supplement for the flip back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use order:

```sql
select * from something Offset (select case when count(id)>10 then count(id)-10 end from something)
```

Answer (score 1):

select * from (select * from log order by 1  desc limit 50) tmp order by 1

Answer (score 1):

Your idea was not bad at all:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY record_date ASC LIMIT 5 
    OFFSET (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable) - 5;
```

The only thing you are missing is how to avoid a negative offset when there are less than 5 rows, which will trigger a: "***[2201X] ERROR: OFFSET must not be negative***".

**Solution:** Use the [GREATEST](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/postgresql/greatest-least-function) function.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY record_date LIMIT 5
    OFFSET GREATEST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable) - 5, 0);
```

That way, when there are less than 5 rows on your table, it will set an offset of 0, which is exactly what you need in that case. In my opinion this is a cleaner-simpler solution, instead of flipping the result set.