# Changing the output of the mySQL DATE function

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am working on a site that displays dates from a mySQL database. I currently have these columns in the database: `id`, `title`, `date_start`, `date_stop`, `time_start`, `time_stop`, `image`, and `hyperlink`.

I want `date_start` and `date_end` to display as December 24, instead of 2012-12-24.

My current code is this:

```
<html>
<style>
html{
font-family: arial;
}
</style>
<h1>Local Events</h1>
<?php
//mysql connection
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') OR DIE ("Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.");

//selecting the table
mysql_select_db('local');

//query
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events3 WHERE date_end >= CURDATE() ORDER BY date_start LIMIT 5;");

//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597098/get-the-last-n-rows-in-the-database-in-order
//SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY date_start DESC LIMIT 5 ::Works but still need to reverse order
//SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;
//SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;
//WHERE year = '2012'

//fetch results

        WHILE($rows= mysql_fetch_array($query)):

                $id =                   $rows['id'];   
                $title =                $rows['title'];

                $date_start =       $rows['date_start'];
                $date_end =             $rows['date_end'];

                $time_start =           $rows['time_start'];
                $time_end =             $rows['time_end'];

                $location =             $rows['location'];
                $description =          $rows['description'];
                $image =                $rows['image'];
                $hyperlink =            $rows['hyperlink'];                    
?>
<?php
        //ID/ Title Display
        echo "<b>ID:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";                                    echo "$id<br>";
        echo "<b>Title:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";                                 echo "$title<br>";

        //Date Display
        echo "<b>Date Start:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";                   
        echo "$date_start"; echo '&nbsp;-&nbsp';         echo "$date_end<br>";

        //Time Display
        echo "<b>Time Frame:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";                   
        echo date('g:i a',strtotime($time_start)); echo"&nbsp;-&nbsp;"; echo date('g:i a',strtotime($time_end)); echo"<br>";
        //      echo "$time_start";     echo "&nbsp;-&nbsp;";           echo "$time_end<br>";


        echo "<b>Location:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";              echo "$location<br>";
        echo "<b>Description:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";   echo "$description<br><br><br>";



        endwhile;
// SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;
?>

</html>
```

That code makes the site look like:

```
ID:   8
Title:   Christmas
Date Start:   2012-12-44 - 2012-12-25
Time Frame:   9:00 am - 1:00 pm
Location:   Everywhere
Description:   Test event
```

I want the date start area to say December 24 - 25. How do I do this?

Comment: how about if you have this dates? `2012-12-25` until `2013-02-15`?

Comment: "functions to display as December **24**, instead of 2012-12-**25**" - I'm wondering what kind of function would do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT 
    id, title , 
    DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%M/%d') as `Date Start`,
    other_columns
FROM
    mytable
```

Comment: But do what with my current query? Because my current query also sorts the data.

Comment: i only wanted to show you the use of DATE_FORMAT function of mysql and you can see Kuya John has added what you really need

Comment: How could I incorporate that into my current mySQL Query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%M %d'), ' - ', DAY(date_end)) newDate
FROM table1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfa3d/3)

*follow-up question: how about if you have this dates? `2012-12-25 until 2013-02-15`?*

Comment: But where would i put that in my php?

Comment: just add this in your query `CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%M %d'), ' - ', DAY(date_end)) newDate` and in your php `$dateSched =           $rows['newDate']; echo "<b>Date Start:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"; echo $dateSched;`

Comment: But my current query sorts the displayed data too?

Comment: yep, sort it by `ORDER BY date_start` (*not newDate*)

Comment: Current Query: SELECT * FROM events3 WHERE date_end >= CURDATE() ORDER BY date_start LIMIT 5    Now how to combine the two?

Comment: `SELECT *, CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%M %d'), ' - ', DAY(date_end)) newDate FROM events3 WHERE date_end >= CURDATE() ORDER BY date_start LIMIT 5`

Comment: Now if the days are the same, how to make it not show the hyphen(-) and the second number? Lol along with the 0 before the dates because I'm getting this Date Start:   December 04 - 11

Comment: Sorry im new to mySQl if you can't tell. haha

Comment: The only thing is I want to remove the second one from occuring, this one seems to go in the middle? Im not sure? What would the query become from being: SELECT *, CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%M %d'), ' - ', DAY(date_end)) newDate FROM events3 WHERE date_end >= CURDATE() ORDER BY date_start LIMIT 5