# Postgres ORDER BY twice DESC then ASC

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a recursive query

```
With RECURSIVE tree AS
 (
 SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = 83
 UNION
 SELECT t.*
      From comments t
 JOIN tree rt ON rt.parent_id = t.id

 )
 SELECT * from tree ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

How would I order it one more time by ASC?

**Edit1:** tried this solution: 
[Get the last N rows in the database in order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597098/get-the-last-n-rows-in-the-database-in-order)

```
With RECURSIVE tree AS
 (
 SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = 83
 UNION
 SELECT t.*
      From comments t
 JOIN tree rt ON rt.parent_id = t.id

 )
 select * from (SELECT * from tree ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) order by id
```

Gives me an error:

```
ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias
```

Comment: Can you explain what the desired order would be?

Comment: I tried that solution it didn't work thats why I'm posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL all table expressions (the selects right after `FROM`) need to be named. That is, they need to have an alias. Just add any alias. For example I added `x`, as in:

```
With RECURSIVE tree AS
 (
 SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = 83
 UNION
 SELECT t.*
      From comments t
 JOIN tree rt ON rt.parent_id = t.id

 )
 select * from (SELECT * from tree ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) x order by id
```

Did you spot it?

Comment: thank u for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (SELECT * from tree ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 5) t order by comment_id
```

Comment: ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias